# ARIMA GARCH NAGARCH model invertibility conditions

Tags: time-series, arima, garch

According to ARIMA model and GARCH model whose terms are in linear form, we can insist on invertibility conditions involving coefficients. But for instance in nonlinear asymmetric GARCH model(NAGARCH) whose terms may be nonlinear( such as multiplication of past residuals and past variance terms  ) I have not seen any invertibility conditions unlike stationarity conditions. How can we determine the invertibility conditions for NAGARCH?

Comment: @Richard Hardy I deem that you are one of the most capable person in realms of time series on this forum. Could you help me?

Comment: @Richard Hardy. As far as I remember, you said you were among the limited numbers of people who has significant knowledge about types of GARCH model. Could you help me about that?

Comment: @Richard Hardy could you see my question?